# Highlighting table view cell will not highlight subviews of table view cell using objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cagradientlayer

I had table view with customised cell. In each row of the table view cell, there is subview with gradient colour and each row's background colour is different from subview's colour.

when I tap or touch each table view cell, then it is only highlighting background of tableview cell and not highlighting the subview. All the cell contents are not highlighted with green colour.

1. I tried removing gradient layer of subview and added background colour to it, then all the cell contents are highlighting but with gradient layer it is not highlighting.
2. Also I need to save the status, whether it is highlighted or not, how can i achieve this?

Here is the screen shot,

[image]

in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
 UIView *selection_color         = [[UIView alloc] init];
 selection_color.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
 cell.selectedBackgroundView     = selection_color;

 UIView *view = [UIView alloc] init];
 view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
 view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
 view.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:197/255.0 green:197.0/255.0 blue:197.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
 view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
 view.tag = 10;
 [cell.contentView addSubview: view];

 NSArray *gradient_colors    = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, nil];
 NSArray *gradient_locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0.0],[NSNumber numberWithInt:1.0], nil];

 CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
 gradientLayer.colors        = gradient_colors;
 gradientLayer.locations     = gradient_locations;
 gradientLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
 gradientLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds;
 [view.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
```

guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: How are you adding the gradient layer? Can you show the code for that?

Comment: i have edited my post.

Comment: @Ishanhanda i edited my post with gradient layer for subview, suggest me what i need to modify?

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the setHighlighted method in your custom tableview cell, and set the highlight on the subviews as well.

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
  [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
  self.customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Comment: i have edited my post, when i need to call this above method.

Comment: You don't call this method directly, it is called by the Tableview when a cell is highlighted. You need to implement your custom background view inside the cell.

Comment: shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath, didHighlightRowAtIndexPath, didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath. Only above three methods are called. setHighlighted is not called.

Comment: make sure you override the setHiglighted:Animated: method

Comment: how to override? i am not getting